# Framework.js gives error on internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm facing a problem on internet explorer 8 while including the IN API. Here's the code, I'm not doing anything fancy at all, just including some files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: <?php echo API_KEY . "\n"; ?>
  credentials_cookie: true
  authorize: true
</script>

<script type="in/login" data-onAuth="onLinkedInAuth"></script>
```

And then I have this onLinkedInAuth function defined that isn't doing much right now. This piece of code produces an error in IE8, coming from the framework.js file, refering to line 1070 :

```
b.fn.apply((b.scope||window),c)
```

Has anyone fixed that before ?!

Comment: What's the actual error that it produces?

Comment: Basically that it can't access something of null